# Marshalling byte array in WinAPI struct SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke, marshalling

Please excuse me if my terminology isn't correct I am new to P/Invoke & marshalling. I am trying to execute the `NtQuerySystemInformation` method from `ntdll.dll`. The P/Invoke website suggests [[link](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll.ntquerysysteminformation)]

```cs
[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
public static extern NtStatus NtQuerySystemInformation(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass, IntPtr SystemInformation, uint SystemInformationLength, out uint ReturnLength);
```

However it is the information in `IntPtr SystemInformation` that I am interested in. So instead I am attempting to implement

```
NtQuerySystemInformation(SYSTEM_INFORMATION_CLASS SystemInformationClass, SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION SystemInformation, uint SystemInformationLength, out uint ReturnLength)
```

I am trying to marshal the `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION` with a `StructLayout` attribute.

```cs
public struct UNICODE_STRING
{
    public ushort Length;
    public ushort MaximumLength;
    public IntPtr buffer;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 8)]
struct LARGE_INTEGER
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Int64 QuadPart;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt32 LowPart;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public Int32 HighPart;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public uint NextEntryOffset;
    public uint NumberOfThreads;
    >>public byte[48] Reserved1;<<
    public UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    public long BasePriority;
    public IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
    public IntPtr Reserved2;
    public ulong HandleCount;
    public ulong SessionId;
    public IntPtr Reserved3;
    public Int64 PeakVirtualSize;
    public Int64 VirtualSize;
    public ulong Reserved4;
    public Int64 PeakWorkingSetSize;
    public Int64 WorkingSetSize;
    public IntPtr Reserved5;
    public Int64 QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    public IntPtr Reserved6;
    public Int64 QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public Int64 PageFileUsage;
    public Int64 PeakPageFileUsage;
    public Int64 PrivatePageCount;
    >>public LARGE_INTEGER[6] Reserved7;<<
}
```

I am using [this website](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/converting-c-data-types-to-c/?ID=38db6001-45e5-41a3-ab39-8004450204b3) to help me translate WinAPI types into C# built-in types. I derived as much using the struct definition in `winternl.h`

```cs
typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    ULONG NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG NumberOfThreads;
    BYTE Reserved1[48];
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    KPRIORITY BasePriority;
    HANDLE UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID Reserved2;
    ULONG HandleCount;
    ULONG SessionId;
    PVOID Reserved3;
    SIZE_T PeakVirtualSize;
    SIZE_T VirtualSize;
    ULONG Reserved4;
    SIZE_T PeakWorkingSetSize;
    SIZE_T WorkingSetSize;
    PVOID Reserved5;
    SIZE_T QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    PVOID Reserved6;
    SIZE_T QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    SIZE_T PagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PeakPagefileUsage;
    SIZE_T PrivatePageCount;
    LARGE_INTEGER Reserved7[6];
} SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION;
```

But I am unsure as to how to deal with `BYTE Reserved1[48]` and `LARGE_INTEGER Reserved[6]`. My current code above does not work. I am not interested in their values so it does not matter to me if the data is unintelligible.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,1281

Comment: @HansPassant Using this I have managed to call NtQuerySystemInformation correctly. I am getting an error though. It is unrelated to the original question but maybe you can help me? I am getting an access violation error? (Even when ran as administrator). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: In C++ implementation that I know works, space in virtual memory is allocated to the SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pointer before `NtQuerySystemInformation` is called, is this something I need to do in my C# code too? I am initialising the pointer with `SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION p = new SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION();` which I thought was correct

Comment: The access violation is probably due to incorrectly sized fields on some of the above.

Comment: pinvoke.net has had a long history of providing incorrect information. It's about time to let that die. [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) is the alternative. If you run into any issues, [let them know](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32/issues).

Answer (score 1):

This is called an inline array. There are various ways of dealing with this. The official way is to use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,` for example:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public uint NextEntryOffset;
    public uint NumberOfThreads;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 48)]
    public byte[48] Reserved1;
    public UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
    public int BasePriority;
    public IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
    public IntPtr Reserved2;
    public uint HandleCount;
    public uint SessionId;
    public IntPtr Reserved3;
    public IntPtr PeakVirtualSize;
    public IntPtr VirtualSize;
    public uint Reserved4;
    public IntPtr PeakWorkingSetSize;
    public IntPtr WorkingSetSize;
    public IntPtr Reserved5;
    public IntPtr QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
    public IntPtr Reserved6;
    public IntPtr QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
    public IntPtr PageFileUsage;
    public IntPtr PeakPageFileUsage;
    public IntPtr PrivatePageCount;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public long[6] Reserved7;
}
```

Note that there are other type mismatches in your struct which I have corrected.

However this can lead to heavy copying of values. So for that you may wish to instead just embed a bunch of `long` fields. This is what is done [in .NET itself](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,1281) when it uses this struct.

```cs
     [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
     struct SystemProcessInformation
     {
         public uint NextEntryOffset;
         public uint NumberOfThreads;
         long SpareLi1;
         long SpareLi2;
         long SpareLi3;
         public long CreateTime;
         public long UserTime;
         public long KernelTime;
         public UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
         public int BasePriority;
         public IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
         public IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;
         public uint HandleCount;
         public uint SessionId;
         public IntPtr PageDirectoryBase;
         public IntPtr PeakVirtualSize;
         public IntPtr VirtualSize;
         public uint   PageFaultCount;
         public IntPtr PeakWorkingSetSize;
         public IntPtr WorkingSetSize;
         public IntPtr QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage;
         public IntPtr QuotaPagedPoolUsage;
         public IntPtr QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage;
         public IntPtr QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage;
         public IntPtr PagefileUsage;
         public IntPtr PeakPagefileUsage;
         public IntPtr PrivatePageCount;

         long ReadOperationCount;
         long WriteOperationCount;
         long OtherOperationCount;
         long ReadTransferCount;
         long WriteTransferCount;
         long OtherTransferCount;
     }
```